# Providing no arguments to sourced script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that can be "configured", as it sources the file located at the first argument. Now I want to pass all other arguments as arguments to the script sourced. When I pass parameters, everything is as I expect it. But when I don't pass parameters, the parameters from my outer script are taken instead.

Suppose I have the following two scripts:

outer.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ${@}
MYARGS=${@:2}
echo $MYARGS 

. inner.sh $MYARGS
```

inner.sh

```
echo "inner arguments: $@"
echo "first: $1"
```

Results on the command line:

```
$ ./outer.sh one two #this is what I expected
one two
two
inner arguments: two
first: two

$ ./outer.sh one #this is what puzzles me
one

inner arguments: one
first: one
```

The result of the first invocation of my script is exactly what I expect, as I provided the parameter `two`. But the second invocation shows what I am trying to achieve: I don't any arguments passed to the script.

Is there any solution, which does not require me to change the values of the variables in my outer script?

Comment: execute the second script instead of sourcing it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the second scripts sets a few variables I need later in the first script, and I don't want to export them into the environment as they are are only needed for running the first script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the current set of arguments to be restored later, then modify the set before sourcing `inner.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

current_args=( "$@" )
set -- "${@:2}"   # Configure arguments for inner.sh
. inner.sh
set -- "${current_args[@]}"  # Restore arguments for outer.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

No. When you source a script the lines in the script are read and executed *in the current interpreter*. This means that it affects and is affected by the current execution environment including but not limited to variables, functions, options, and traps.